# SHAREPOINT SERVER 2016 and UBUNTU

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, browsers, ubuntu

I have a computer with windows server, and I can access this windows server from another computer with the WINDOWS operating system with the firefox browser.

When I try to access from another computer with the UBUNTU operating system, and with firefox browser, I can not.

Does anyone know where the problem is?
Thank you

Comment: What is the message in browser from ubuntu? Can you check if ping is correctly linking to the SharePoint server? Which authentication have you used? If you have only Windows Authenticate, I don'T know if its suitable with Ubuntu and SharePoint.

Comment: Problem solved. In the URL, it did not recognize the name of the computer. I changed it by its IP address and it worked. Thank you.  Another thing. I´m trying to connect my application with Sharepoint through the REST API. I´ve an authentication problem, because I don´t know the URL adress of the login page because when I connect to the sharepoint server, I automatically jump a window to authenticate, but it does not take me to an authentication page. It is what is called "digest authentication". Dou know if there is an authentication URL? Thank you

Comment: Youre welcome, i add it as answer, mark it as right answer, Thanks :)

Comment: Create second post for this authentication its different case. Better to communicate through post no comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the message in browser from ubuntu? Can you check if ping is correctly linking to the SharePoint server? Which authentication have you used? If you have only Windows Authenticate, I don'T know if its suitable with Ubuntu and SharePoint.